# Relationship between high and low level programming languages

Tags: c++, assembly

How low and high level programing languges are related with each other? As an example, assembler language and C++ work at different levels but, what kind of logic exist between those levels? Let´s suposse that I write a Hello World! program in C++, I compile and run it. What thing do I need to care about in order to make more efficient my code on the assembler level??

Comment: The 'logic' is essentially that C++ generates assembly language.

Comment: The C++ "compiler" generates the assembly language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go to the hardware store and you can find beams and boards and nails and screws and bricks and mortar and all kinds of basic building materials. Combinations of those materials can build a dog house, a people house, an office building, a sidewalk, a road, a mailbox, etc.

C/C++ is the house, the mailbox, the storage shed.  The bricks and boards and nails are the machine language.  The word brick and nail are the assembly language that describe and have a one to one relationship with a single instances of the material.

When you take a line of high level code

```
a = b + c;
```

you cannot run that in that form, not really even interpreted, because the interpreter itself is a program made up of smaller pieces.  A compiler be it a human doing it by hand or a program evolved from other programs, is used to interpret that line of high level code, allocate registers or memory for each of the variables and pick from the available instructions in the instruction set and order of those instructions to create a program that the processor can understand, that performs the same functional task.  give this problem to 100 people and you may get anywhere from 1 to 100 different solutions, there is always more than one way to have a functional equivalent to a high level program in the instruction set that the processor understands.

Assembly language is ideally just a human readable and writable form of the instruction set for that processor, so that we dont have to stare at bits and bytes of machine code.  an assembler is a much simpler program that converts the assembly language mnemonics into machine code, ideally one asm instruction to one machine instruction, but the assembler may add other features to make the task of hand programming (or even compiler generated asm) easier on the human.

the "logic" between these levels is other programs called compilers, assemblers and linkers that "convert" the high level program into a functional equivalent at the low level.  The processor can only actually execute the low level.  The high level source code is just a blob of data no different than a book, web page, audio file, video, etc to the processor, it cannot understand it without a program in its native language that can parse that data.

Comment: I think this is the best answer that I´m going to get. Thank you very much for share your knowlkedge.